# Getting property/object-name from JSON-List in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSON-String:

```
{"object":{"4711":{"type":"volume","owner":"john doe","time":1426156658,"description":"Jodel"},"0815":{"type":"fax","owner":"John Doe","time":1422900028,"description":"","page_count":1,"status":"ok","tag":["342ced30-7c34-11e3-ad00-00259073fd04","342ced33-7c34-11e3-ad00-00259073fd04"]}},"status":"ok"}
```

A human readable screenshot of that data:

[image: JSON-Data]

I want to get the Values "4711" and "0815" of that data. I iterate through the data with the following code:

```
JObject tags = GetJsonResponse();
var objectContainer = tags.GetValue("object");
if (objectContainer != null) {
  foreach (var tag in objectContainer) {
    var property=tag.HowToGetThatMagicProperty();
  }
}
```

At the position `"var property="` I want to get the values "4711".

I could just use String-Manipulation

```
string tagName = tag.ToString().Split(':')[0].Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

but there must be a better, more OOP-like way

Comment: You could deserialize directly into a model of said object, or if your in Model View Controller, you could do a JsonResult with a parameter of the Model to actually pass the information into.

Comment: @Greg No MVC (but I understand what you meant) :) Because I am only interested in that single string-value I do not want to create objects for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the `"object"` object as a `JObject` explicitly, you can access the `Key` property on each member inside of the `JObject`. Currently `objectContainer` is a `JToken`, which isn't specific enough:

```
JObject objectContainer = tags.Value<JObject>("object");

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> tag in objectContainer)
{
    var property = tag.Key;

    Console.WriteLine (property); // 4711, etc.
}
```

`JObject` exposes an implementation of `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` that returns `KeyValuePair<string, JToken>`s containing the name and value of each property in the object.

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/QbK6MU

Answer (score 1):

I got the results using this

```
        foreach (var tag in objectContainer)
        {
            var property = tag.Path.Substring(tag.Path.IndexOf(".") + 1);
            Console.WriteLine(property);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: This is similar to OP's method using string manipulation, Didn't realize it was edited at the time of writing my answer

Comment: Sorry for that. :) But your answer is a "bit" nicer as it does not uses .ToString()